# When building package with debuild, I'm unable to force make to look into certain directories for *.h files

Tags: deb, packaging, debuild

What I'm trying to do is to build a deb package with *debuild* command, given I have provided all the necessary files like debian/control, debian/rules, debian/changelog etc...
When trying to run debuild, it starts, but in the beginning fails with message:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/VS/pxfbld/pxf/external-table'
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DPXF_API_VERSION=\"16\" -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o src/pxfprotocol.o src/pxfprotocol.c
In file included from src/pxfbridge.h:27:0,
                 from src/pxfprotocol.c:21:
src/cdb/cdbvars.h:23:63: **fatal error: catalog/gp_segment_config.h: No such file or directory**
compilation terminated.
```

What do I want from it - I want to make it get compiled with additional include dirs aka added: -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server

I tried to put this into debian rules as:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server"
```

I tried to put it as

```
export DEB_CXXFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND= -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server
export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND= -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server
export DEB_CPPFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND= -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server
export DEB_CXXFLAGS_APPEND= -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server
export DEB_CFLAGS_APPEND= -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server
export DEB_CPPFLAGS_APPEND= -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server
```

I also executed

```
export DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
include /usr/share/dpkg/buildflags.mk

export CPPFLAGS=$CPPFLAGS" -I/usr/local/gpdb/include -I/usr/local/gpdb/include/postgresql/server"
```

Neither option worked for me.. meaning these lines do not appear in gcc params...

Could you advise what I'm doing worng, please?
I just do not want to put those header files to this repository, I want debuild to read it from where I ask it to read them...

Perhaps this is not possible .

Thank you in advance!